# How to express y in terms of x based on a diagram

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

The above diagram shows the intersection of two roads, their widths being 16m and 9m. If RN = x , and MP = y, how would you express y in terms of x. Is it by using the method of congruent triangles here? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: The word is _similar_ triangles. Try it and show us what you can do (and then maybe ask about what you can't do).

Comment: This is not a question about "linear algebra". Tags are changed.